# Iteratively improving ML model on a small dataset

Tags: dataset, machine-learning-model, training, data-science-model

I have a spam classification model which I created using a very small dataset.I have exported it as shown

```
#saving model 
import joblib 

joblib.dump(spam_classifier, '../models/spam-detection-model.pkl')
```

Since I have limited computation power I want to retrain it such that it improves upon the new data as well. You can assume this problem as creating a model using very large dataset which is divided into chunks and then feeding a new chunk of data each day. All I know is this

```
model = joblib.load(./models/spam-detection-model.pkl')
# Code to train on new data such that it retains what is learned from previous chunk as well.
# Is something like this possible 
improved_model = model.fit_and_improve_while_retaining_old_knowledge('new data')
```